# Easy way to have checkmark below image for WPF checkbox?

Tags: wpf, checkbox

In a WPF window I got a CheckBox containing an image, like this:

```
<CheckBox>
  <Image Source="/Bsoft.Clients.Warenwirtschaft;component/Resources/MyImage.png" />
</CheckBox>
```

Using this, the checkmark is displayed left to the image.

Is there an easy way to move the checkmark to below the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of an easy way to do this.

You could either use some panel and have a checkbox independent from your image...

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image .../>
    <CheckBox .../>
</StackPanel>
```

Which might not be too much trouble if encapsulated in a `UserControl`.

Or you change the ControlTemplate of the CheckBox, which is more difficult i think. Default templates can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx).

Comment: If the image is not inside the CheckBox, clicking on the image to change the checkbox does not work anymore.
I'll probably have to look into the templates...

Comment: You could link that i think, if you want i'll try to give an example.

Comment: I've had a look, the information behind the link is good - those templates sure are huge, but thats ok.